# Why we must continue using server and client languages for ever

Tags: javascript

i know that server language is needed  mainly  for saving  security to code

i think if the future  browser stop to show page source ,  and javascript or any other client  language is upgraded  to work with server databases it will be great thing
my question  is
why browser must show my  javascript code ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons which I can think of why browser needs to see the code:

1. To make sure that the code is legitimate and people are not writing hacking code.
2. Google bots need to see the code so it can use it in their search results.

Comment: yes  google can see that code   and user can not!   ,  haking code??  combiled application with haking code is captured by antivirus  while  users can't  see that code